# How to increase array size during runtime to avoid garbage value at the end

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation

Here i am working with a code which will count the number of "1" present in an array at a time.say, my array is

```
int arr[12] = {0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1};

Number of "1" present at a time are (2,4,1)
```

I want to store the result in an array calle **store**.As the sequence can vary,At the very beginning i don't know what size of array i have to declare to store them.Worst case will be there might be a array like the following:

```
int arr[12]={0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1};
```

so i dynamically allocated an array half the size of actual array to store the worst case.But If not the worst case i get garbage value at the end of store array.I would like to know how i can dynamically increase array size at runtime so that i don't need to deal with any garbage value

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){

   int arr[12] = {0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1};
   int size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

   int *store =(int *)malloc((size/2)*sizeof(int));

   int i=0,j=0,count=0;
   while(arr[i]<size){
        while(arr[i]==0 && arr[i]<size){
            i++;
        }
        if(i==size){
           break;
        }
        while(arr[i]==1){
            i++;
            count++;
        }
        store[j]=count;
        j++;
        count=0;
   }
   for(i=0;i<size/2;i++){

       printf("%d ",store[i]);
   }

}
```

Comment: Even if you resize the array, you need to keep track of how many entries are valid (or the size of the array if it only contains valid entries).  So, you don't ever need to look at the garbage because you know at all times how much of the array is not garbage.  Note that you can't start out with an empty array — they aren't allowed in Standard C.  So, you have to be careful with arrays, at all times.

Answer (score 1):

Use `realloc`

```
//size2 has the size of the new array to be stored
store = realloc(store, size2 * sizeof int);

if (store == NULL)
{
   // Reallocation failed -- Take appropriate action
   printf ("Reallocation failed");
   exit(1);
}
```

Comment: It is not clear to me yet..can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `calloc`

`store = calloc(store,sizeof(int));`